# Displaying only images with a specific class or id using the Magnific Popup

Tags: jquery, html, magnific-popup

I am using magnific popup (lightbox) and there are several images in my container. All these images are displayed on a website. Now I want to open the popup in the gallery mode upon click on image and showing only images with a specific class (for example class 'one'). Is it possible?

**HTML**

```
<div class="zoom-gallery" > 
    <a href="a.jpg"><img class="one" src="a.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="b.jpg"><img class="two" src="b.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="c.jpg"><img class="one" src="c.jpg"/></a>
    <a href="d.jpg"><img class="three" src="d.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.zoom-gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick:true,
    closeBtnInside: true,        
    gallery: {
        enabled: true
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to move class to `a` and set `delegate: 'a.one',`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is still looking, here is solution that use opposite apporach. In other words, you can hide images with specific class and show the rest.

This worked for me ( I located my images into unordered lists and wrapped them inside `.my_gallery` div ):

```
$('.my_gallery').each(function() { // iterate over unordered list placed inside '.my_gallery' div
    $(this).magnificPopup({        
       delegate: 'a:not(.hidden)', // the select all except hidden ones
       type: 'image',
       removalDelay: 1000,
       gallery: {
           enabled:true
       }
   });
});
```